# Display message if internet connection is not available

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I made a simple WebView App for my Website using Xamarin.Forms. When the device has no internet access I take the follow display:

[image: Image 1]

But I want to display a message if there is no internet access on the device instead of the above display.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }
        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Broswer.Source = "https://mywebpage.com/";
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            if (Broswer.CanGoBack)
            {
                Broswer.GoBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">

    <WebView x:Name="Broswer" HeightRequest="1920" WidthRequest="1080"/>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway i found a solution to my problem,by using `Xam.Plugin.Connectivity`.

Special Thanks to @Jack Hua - MSFT, @Wilson Vargas.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Connectivity;

namespace MyApp
{

    [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += Current_ConnectivityChanged;
        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error Title", "Error Msg", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                Broswer.Source = "https://mypage.com/";
            }
        }

        private async void Current_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.IsConnected)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error Title", "Error Msg", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                Broswer.Source = "https://mypage.com/";
            }
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed() 
        {
            if (Broswer.CanGoBack)
            {
                Broswer.GoBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios) to check the Internet conntection. It's easier.

1.install [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Cios) to your project.

2.[Use Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#get-started)

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
{
    // Connection to internet is available
}
```

3.You can also check the type of [connection profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.connectionprofile?view=xamarin-essentials) like:

```
var profiles = Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles;
if (profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.WiFi))
{
    // Active Wi-Fi connection.
}
```

Comment: Didn't work either.   Doesn't apprear alert when device hasn't internet connection and it still show the image i post above. I follow all the steps you said. **1.** Install `Xamarin.Essentials`  **2.** Add the library on `MainPage.xaml.cs` **3.** Made a simple `if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Alert", "No Internet", "OK");
            }` on `public MainPage()`

Comment: @Fotic It should work. Did you access the Connectivity functionality as described in the [get-started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#get-started) section?

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Xam.Plugin.Connectivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity/) NuGet Package.

And in your `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) {  
            Broswer.Source = "https://mywebpage.com/"; 
        } else {  
            DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Your alert", "OK");  
        } 
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (Broswer.CanGoBack)
        {
            Broswer.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It didnt work for me. Doesn't apprear alert when device hasn't internet connection and it still show the image i post above. 
I follow all the steps you said. 
**1.** Install `Xam.Plugin.Connectivity` 
**2.** Add the library on `MainPage.xaml.cs`